# Collapse cell via code, or key shortcut in jupyterlab

Tags: ipython, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to collapse the cell itself - and **not** the output, either via a hotkey combo, or a line of code?
I know that by clicking on the blue line on the side it collapses it, but would want to streamline this.
[image]
[image]